# How to apply progressbar for the original indexes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, progress-bar, enumerate

I would like to use the `progressbar` module and I use this method:

```
bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(maxval=len(c)).start()
for i,idx in enumerate(c):
     # do something
     bar.update(idx)
```

Unfortunately, in my case I can not use `enumerate`, because my list`c` is in the form `[0,1,4,5,7,9]` and I need to keep the original values, and I would like to index `for i in c`. Because indexes from the list `c` speak about elements from another list, which should be searched yet. And the `for-loop` is inside the `while-loop` where the `c` list is different at every new step.
How to deal with this? Maybe different progressbar?

Comment: problem solved, just change `for i, idx in enumerate(c)` to `for idx, i in enumerate(c)`;)